# Boost error : Boost.Filesystem V3 and later requires std::wstring support

Tags: c++, boost

What does this error mean and how to solve it ?

```
Boost.Filesystem V3 and later requires std::wstring support
```

I have just started using boost::filesystem and got this error. Simply adding following line causes the error.

```
#include <Boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

I am compiling on Windows 7, not sure about the compiler, I am using Devc++ and there is a MinGW64 folder in Devc++ directory, so maybe its MinGW64 ?

Comment: What OS and compiler? What options are you passing to the compiler?

Comment: @AlanStokes I am compiling on Windows 7 and am not sure about the compiler, I am using Devc++ and there is a MinGW64 folder in Devc++ directory, so maybe its MinGW64 ?

Comment: @StudentX: Have you tried using a development environment that less... outdated than DevC++?

Comment: @NicolBolas is it possibly an error associated with compiler ? I am downloading latest MinGW, lets see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you look at the boost header you get:

```
# if defined( BOOST_NO_STD_WSTRING )
#   error Configuration not supported: Boost.Filesystem V3 and later requires std::wstring support
# endif
```

So.. then you want to know what `BOOST_NO_STD_WSTRING` is.. well that's located in Boost/Config directory. Running a quick directory wide ctrl + f you get:

```
boost\config\platform\amigaos.hpp
boost\config\platform\symbian.hpp
boost\config\stdlib\libstdcpp3.hpp
boost\config\stdlib\modena.hpp
boost\config\stdlib\sgi.hpp
boost\config\stdlib\stlport.hpp
```

So if you use those platforms or standard library that macro will be defined for you. So based on your information, you might be running on libstdc++3

Comment: I got following stdlib results : Boost\config\stdlib\stlport.hpp,
Boost\config\stdlib\sgi.hpp,
Boost\config\stdlib\modena.hpp,
Boost\config\stdlib\libstdcpp3.hpp